# Progress bar for the form

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create a progress bar for my form but it still doesn't work. After loading the form, I would like my progress bar to move from 0 percent to 100 and finish loading. I still can't see why my progress bar is not working.

**My code looks like this**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="newProductForm" id="newProductForm">
  <input type="file" name="img" class="custom-input-file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg" required id="id_img">
  <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control form-control-emphasized" id="category" placeholder="Wpisz kategorie..." maxlength="200" required>

  <div class="progress">
    <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
      0%
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" onClick="submitFunction();" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="buttonSubmitProduct">
    <span style="display:block;" id="buttonText">
      Submit
    </span>
    <span style="display:none;" id="buttonSipner">
      Loading......
    </span>
  </button>

</form>
```

**My AJAX and JS:**

```
<script>
function submitFunction() {
  document.getElementById('buttonSubmitProduct').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('buttonText').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('buttonSipner').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('newProductForm').submit();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('newProductForm').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('newProductForm')[0]);

    $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {

          if (e.lengthComputable) {

            console.log('Bytes Loaded: ' + e.loaded);
            console.log('Total Size: ' + e.total);
            console.log('Percentage Uploaded: ' + (e.loaded / e.total))

            var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

            $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%').text(percent + '%');

          }

        });

        return xhr;
      },
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function() {
        location.replace("/?okey=smile");
      }
    });

  });

});
</script>
```

I don't see any errors in the console. Why is my code not working?

Comment: I think xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function() {}) only works for uploading files.

Comment: Do you think that in this case the form should contain only files, without additional fields? My form contains file upload and text input fields.

Comment: There you are just submitting a form, nothing is uploading to the server. xhr.upload works only when you upload files to the server. You can check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload

Comment: hmm but in my form I have files. Do you think my code can't see it?

Comment: After reviewing your form carefully I don't see any file type field.

Comment: I was editing my form, can I see you again? I will be grateful for any comments.

Answer (score 1):

What about use the progress HTML5 tag to do that?

```js
//calling the function in window.onload to make sure the HTML is loaded
window.onload = function() {
     var pos = 0; 

    var t = setInterval(move, 75);
  
    function move() {
        if(pos >= 400) {
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else {
            pos += 4;
            bar.value = pos/4;
        }
    }
};
```

```css
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;

}

#bar {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

progress {
  text-align: center;
}
progress:after {
  content: attr(value)'%';
}

progress:before {
  content: 'progress ';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
 <progress id="bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
            
        </div>
       
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: note: this is not a solution for your code, but another point of view to start